# Print the Mean with Label "Mean"

Tags: r

How you do include/print labels for statistical output using R code?  For example, calculate Mean, Median and StdDev but label them "Mean" "Median" and "Std Dev"

Comment: `x <-(4,5,6,7)`; `Mean<–mean(x)`

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]!

Answer (score 2):

This is a broad question, and it depends on what exactly you need, but you can create a named vector with the labels and values you're looking for:

```
x <- rnorm(10)
my_stats <- c(Mean = mean(x), Median = median(x), "Std Dv" = sd(x))
my_stats
#       Mean      Median      Std Dv 
# 0.14624129 -0.03570861  0.77759991
```

EDIT:

Expanding on Silver_80s comment, if you want to print some text and interpolate a variable you can use `cat`.

```
Mean <- mean(x)
cat("Mean =", Mean)
# Mean = 0.1462413
```

Comment: With a fully respect to your answer, I think it may be easy to just use `Mean` and then this will print the value without using `cat`.

Comment: I really learn a new thing from your answer. That is writing two separate words such as `"Std Dv"  `. It is really helpful in writing a code.

Comment: Glad you learned something :) Re: using `cat`, I chose that so that it would print both the label and the value to standard output, rather than just the value, since I guessed that's what the OP was looking for. But yes, that's an extra, and typically unnecessary step!

Comment: Amazing. another new thing to learn today. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a function, you can plug any values you want for `x`.

```
 Myfun <-function(x){
  Mean <- mean(x)
  Median <-  median(x)
  Sd <- sd(x)
  return(c(Mean, Median, Sd))
}
x <- rnorm(100)
res <- Myfun(x)
> res
[1] -0.1833411 -0.2313586  1.0102106
```